# Is there any way to launch Tomboy without showing up the main window?

Tags: gnome-panel, tomboy

I saw that there's a applet for tomboy, but if I run the standalone program (`tomboy`) it shows up in the indicators panel (which, to me, is more preferable than having a specific applet for Tomboy).

My question is: **Is there any way to launch Tomboy *without* showing up the main window?**
In Empathy, for example, I can do this by specifing the `-h` option in command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `tomboy` should start Tomboy without showing any window.

There are a few exceptions to this:

- on first run, Tomboy will always show the "Start Here" note (which is the same as running `tomboy --start-here`).  You should be able to turn this off with gconf-editor.
- By default, Ubuntu's Tomboy launcher is set to run `tomboy --search`, which will show the main Search window.
- if Tomboy is already running, the command `tomboy` will show an application window

Comment: +1 Thank you. Open startup applications, find Tomboy, click edit and delete the --search from the command.

Answer (score 1):

If **tomboy** is started without a panel existing or before the panel has loaded then the search window will be displayed. Therefore if you are adding tomboy to your startup programs use `sleep 20 && tomboy` . Alternatively use [**devilspie**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=devilspie) to have the window minimize as soon as it's opened.